# Basic computational problem: exponential expression

Tags: linear-algebra

Back in the 1960s, the group Spiral Staircase performed a song called "I Love You More Today than Yesterday", which includes the lyrics, "I love you more today than yesterday, but only half as much as tomorrow." Suppose the group first sang that song on (say) January 1, 1969. By how much would the singer’s love have increased at the end of one year (January 1, 1970)?

P​lease write your answer as an exponential expression with a base of 2 (i.e. write it as “2^x”)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is asking for help with homework without showing any effort to solve it.

Comment: I tried to solve it but I could not solve.Ut's a question of exponential growth

Comment: if i love you 1 today, how much will i love you tomorrow?